# Cannot implicitly convert type object to microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet, an explicit conversion exists

Tags: asp.net

```cs
public void ExportToexcel(DataSet ds , string strpath)
{
    int inheaderleghth = 3, incliomn = 0, inrow = 0;
    System.Reflection.Missing Default = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    strpath += @"";

    excel.Application exceApp = new excel.Application();
    excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = exceApp.Workbooks.Add(1);

    foreach(DataTable dtbl in ds.Tables)
    {
        //error show below line
        excel.Worksheet ecxelworksheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, excelWorkBook.Sheets[excelWorkBook.Sheets.Count],1,Default);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a soft cast, i.e.,

```
excel.Worksheet ecxelworksheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add(
    Type.Missing,
    excelWorkBook.Sheets[excelWorkBook.Sheets.Count],
    1,Default) as excel.Worksheet;
```